# unbind C-b,and how to set prefix keys at caps lock + a?

Tags: tmux

I want unbind the prefix keys of tmux, use `caps lock-a` instead of `Ctrl-B`

So, `C` means `Ctrl`, and `???` refer to `caps lock`?

```
unbind C-b
set -g prefix ???-a
```

`tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is kind of a hack but achieves the end goal.
Change the behaviour of Capslock to Ctrl and keep the tmux config as C-a.
In OSX this can done using System Preferences > Keyboard > Modifier Keys.
In Linux this can be done using the command 'setxkbmap'